# Multiple comparisons correction methods

Tags: hypothesis-testing, frequentist, bonferroni

I come from a primarily Bayesian background; in my new role at a social networking company, we exclusively use Frequentist statistics and by in large it's in an A/B testing capacity. Often, we'll look at multiple treatments and groups simultaneously. It was discussed that if you set alpha to 0.05 and test 100 combinations of groups and treatments, you can expect 5 type I errors.

So naturally I googled multiple comparisons and found that there are several approaches such as the Bonferroni correction (among others.) What I couldn't tell, from ignorance on my own part, is (A) which of these methods are principled versus heuristic in nature? And (B) what's the method that generalizes best across various contexts in an A/B test environment?

Comment: Bonferroni method is based on an inequality and may be a little too conservative ('reluctant' to declare differences). However, you might start there because it is generally applicable. // Your question is a bit vague on particulars. If you can give an example of one specific design, maybe someone can show the particulars of _ad hoc_ testing for that design.

Comment: From a Bayesian standpoint, the need for Bonferroni style adjustments is, of course, related the prior plausibility of the null hypothesis. Necessarily included in that prior calibration is the prior plausibility of the joint null. While point null plausibility might be zero, it can be replaced with "near point null" plausibility, which may be quite high.

Comment: Please can you clarify 1) What's your boundary between principled and heuristic methods? Many FWER/FDR control methods (e.g. Bonferroni, Benjamini-Hochberg) are based on what I see as principled methods building on a heuristic (choice of alpha), others are heuristic rules that are based on principled theories (e.g. "retest if significant" is based on regression toward the mean); and 2) Whether you have a prior and/or data on how many experiments where H_0 is declared true and is actually true? One might provide different argument for/against FWER/FDR control depending on the numbers.